# Mapping 2 related arrays together

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays

I'm looking for the cleanest and coolest way to merge related arrays together in JavaScript.

My example is this:

I get two JSON arrays from my API: Issues and Locations.

Issues have a `location_id` and as a result I want to give each Issue a `location` field which has the correct `location` object depending on the Issue's `location_id`.

If I had this data:

```
var issues = [{id: 1, title: 'issue 1', location_id: 1}, {id: 12, title: 'issue 1', location_id: 2}];

var locations = [{id: 1, name: 'location 1'}, {id: 2, name: 'location 2'}];
```

The ugly solution would be:

```
for(i = 0; i < issues.length; ++i) {
    for(j = 0; j < locations.length; ++j) {
        if(issues[i].location_id  == locations[j].id) {
            issues[i].location = locations[j];
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

The resulting `issues` array would be:

```
[[object Object] {
    id: 1,
    location: [object Object] {
        id: 1,
        name: "location 1"
     },
     location_id: 1,
     title: "issue 1"
}, [object Object] {
    id: 12,
    location: [object Object] {
        id: 2,
        name: "location 2"
     },
     location_id: 2,
     title: "issue 1"
}]
```

I was trying (and failing) to come up with a shorter solution or even a one liner using .map().

Any guidance appreciated!! :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [`map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) and [`filter`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter):

```
issues.map(function (issue) {
    issue.location = locations.filter(function(location) {
      return issue.location_id === location.id;
    })[0];
    return issue;
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Use an `object` to keep the map, then time complexity will be `O(n+m)` instead of `O(n*m)`.

```js
var issues = [{id: 1, title: 'issue 1', location_id: 1}, {id: 12, title: 'issue 1', location_id: 2}];
var locations = [{id: 1, name: 'location 1'}, {id: 2, name: 'location 2'}];

var binds = function(locationList, issueList) {
  var locMap = {};
  
  // clone. If you want to directly modify the issues, this line is no need.
  issueList = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(issueList));
  
  // construct map from location list.
  locationList.forEach(function(location) {
    locMap[location.id] = location;
  });
  
  // Use the map to bind location and issue.
  issueList.forEach(function(issue) {
    var loc = locMap[issue.location_id];
    if (loc) {
      issue.location = loc;
    }
  });
  
  
  // If you don't want to clone, this line is no need.
  return issueList;
};

var bindResult = binds(locations, issues);
console.log(bindResult);
```

Comment: `Object.create()` would be much better than `JSON.parse(JSON.stringify())`

Comment: @slebetman I tried `var result = Object.create(issueList);` but it seems not work, not familiar with it, how can we use that to do a deep clone?

Comment: Object.create does a shallow clone, not a deep clone. But you don't need a deep clone because you only want to preserve the array instead of the array content.

Answer (score 0):

You can use forEach and filter

```
var result = issues.forEach(function (issue) {
    issue.location = locations.filter(function (location) {
        return location.id == issue.location_id;
    })[0]
})
```

which gives you this output when you console.log(result)

> ```
> [{
>     "id": 1,
>     "title": "issue 1",
>     "location_id": 1,
>     "location": {
>         "id": 1,
>         "name": "location 1"
>     }
> }, {
>     "id": 12,
>     "title": "issue 1",
>     "location_id": 2,
>     "location": {
>         "id": 2,
>         "name": "location 2"
>     }
> }]
> ```

Answer (score 0):

**1.** you can optimize your code to :

```
var locationObj = {};
for(i = 0; i < location.length; i++) {
    locationObj[location[i].id] = location[i];         
}
for(i = 0; i < issues.length; i++) {
    if(issues[i].location_id){
           issues[i].location = locationObj[location_id] 
    }
}
```

It will cache all location in one object and will directly use that location detail it as that object's property.It will be faster in execution rather than using filter or map on location array each time.

**2.** if your location's id and location array's index are in **sync** then following would be a better and faster solution.

```
for(i = 0; i < issues.length; i++) {
        if(issues[i].location_id){
           issues[i].location = locations[location_id-1] 
        }
    }
```

Comment: The `locations[location_id]` thing won't work if you get an array `[{id:15,...},{id:42, ...}]`